# Strange mongodb response format

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb

I have a mongodb database **document** which contains an array

```
{
   "_id":ObjectId("588116a66f7d758b144177f7"),
   "name":"Michael",
   "email":"mick@shift.com",
   "company":"Shift",
   "username":"MichaelP",
   "password":"$2a$10$unH/7anPylxk1x5zk6/so.YcByZqQoBdFi9IlWnHty2gNouUrt7ea",
   "position":"Manager",
   "shifts":[
      "day",
      "day",
      null,
      "night",
      null,
      null,
      null,
      "15"
   ],
   "score":[
      null,
      "550",
      null
   ],
   "__v":0
}
```

I want to print out `shifts[7]` on my webpage. I'm new to node.js but I can print the `{{username}}` or `{{company}}` fine however `shifts[7]` prints as `'{ '0': '1', '1': '5' }'` I imagine it is a simple solution in my index.js however I can't seem to figure it out.

Ill add a shortened version of my index.js code below and thanks for your help.

```
router.get('/hub',ensureAuthenticated, function(req, res, next){
  var collection = db.collection('users');
  var totalHours= req.user.shifts[7] + '';
  var totalhour=0;

  res.render('hub', {username: req.user.username, 
    company: req.user.company, 
    position: req.user.position, 
    totalHours: totalhour 
  });
});
```

Comment: have you tried `var totalHours = req.user.shifts[7].join('')` ?

Comment: You're using nested arrays wrong. A nested array should contain objects.

Comment: Thanks, @JyothiBabuAraja it says that req.user.shifts[7].join is not a function, should i write the function separately?

Comment: @Tom Ill redefine the array as an array of objects and see if that works, thanks!

Comment: @LiveLongCandy51 Sorry `join()` works on arrays, not objects. I thought `shifts[7]` is array.

Comment: You have a object key `totalHours` and a variable named `totalHours`, this can cause unexpected behaviour. What is the output you are expecting? Is it {"15" : 0}?

Comment: In my user model I was defining my array incorrectly i believe, i have since changed it to   shifts: [{
        type: String
    }] @JyothiBabuAraja, thanks for all the help

Answer (score 0):

i think the problem is you are using req.user instead of users response and you are not getting an single object to response so this occurs you should pass _id for getting the single user value and then use it for your further process....

```
router.get('/hub/:id',ensureAuthenticated, function(req, res, next){
var collection = Restangular.One('users',req.user._id);
    collection.get().then(function(err,user){
    var totalHours= users.shifts[7] + '';
    var totalhour=0;
    $scope.user=user;
    $scope.totalHours = user.shift[7];
```

},function(err){
console.log("err",err)});

```
res.render('hub', {username: req.user.username, company:req.user.company, position: req.user.position, totalHours: totalhour})
});
```

for the total hour in html just print {{totalHours}}